# Why outer variable isn't change dynamically when changing inside inner functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code which i use in react. The important things here is that the function returns two `kfl`s, and the first has `kezdet: 3`, the second has `kezdet: 2`. But the `lnkfl` don't have this numbers. My idea was to create an outer scoped variable, the map sets it, then the end of the return, it will be the correct value, then, when the map of `lnkfl` processes the new element, the variable is set the new value, just before the return on the end needs it. But it isn't.

```js
feladatsorok = () => {
        const {nézet, kozvetlenFl, feladatok, lnkfl} = this.state

        let kezdet;
        
        return lnkfl.map(lnkfl => {
            const sor = () => {
                return kozvetlenFl[nézet]
                .filter(kfl => kfl.lnkfl === lnkfl)
                .map(kfl => {
                
                
                
                    kezdet = kfl.kezdet //i want to use kfl.kezdet...
                    
                    
                    
                    const fl = () => {
                        return feladatok[nézet]
                        .filter(fl => fl.legnagyobbSzuloId === kfl.legnagyobbSzuloId)
                        .map(fl => {
                            return <div style={{
                                gridColumn: `${fl.sorkezdet + 1 } / span ${fl.hossz}`,
                                gridRow: fl.szint + "/ span 1",
                                border: "1px solid",
                                overflow: "hidden"
                            }}>
                                {fl.nev}
                            </div>
                        })
                    }
    
                    return <div style = {{
                        gridColumn: `${kfl.dk + 1} / span ${kfl.hossz}`,
                        backgroundColor: "purple",
                        gridRow: "1 / 2",
                        display: "grid",
                        gridTemplateColumns: `repeat( ${kfl.hossz} , 1fr)`,
                        gridTemplateRows: "repeat(" + kfl.sorok + ", 1fr)"
                    }}>
                        {fl()}
                    </div>
                })
            }
            console.log(kezdet)
            return <div style = {{
            
            
            
                gridRow: kezdet + " / span 1", //...here
                
                
                
                gridColumn: "start",
                display: "grid",
                gridTemplateColumns: feladatfilternezetalapjan(),
                gridTemplateRows: "1fr",
                backgroundColor: "yellow"
            }}>
                {sor()}
            </div>
        })
    }
```

The console returns undefined first, then 3. The expected values are 3, and 2. Inside the code snippet, i was shown that where the value of `kezdet` came from, and at the end, where i want to use it. What's the solution for this problem?

Comment: That's some advanced Hungarian notation.

Comment: Please post code in English to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Did you mean to put the `console.log` inside that `sor` function? And no, creating mutable outer-scope variables is never a good idea. Please tell us what the [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) that you're trying to solve.

Comment: I don't know why language is so important in this situation. I have a variable inside the first level scope of the function. At the third level scope i want to assign a value to the variable. At the end of the function i want to use the variable with the value. I don't know how to gain the value at the end of the function with the variable. So it will help if i translate `kezdet` to `beginning`? I don't think so.

Comment: A [mcve] would help. Emphasis on the "minimal" part.

Comment: Everyone picks speaking variable names for a reason: because it supports read- and understandability of code. Your variable names will neither be speaking nor helping for 99,99% of SO users.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're essentially setting `kezdet` inside a `.sor`. But you're calling the `.sor` *after* you first use your `kezdet` --

```
return <div style = {{            
  // for the first 'lnkfl.map' element, 'kezdet' is still undefined here         
  gridRow: kezdet + " / span 1", 
  gridColumn: "start",
  display: "grid",
  gridTemplateColumns: feladatfilternezetalapjan(),
  gridTemplateRows: "1fr",
  backgroundColor: "yellow"
  }}>
     {sor()} // setting 'kezdet' for the first time
  </div>
```

So your `kezdet` is always "one value late".